# display interaction with Julia list comprehension

Tags: julia

```
julia> display([i*j for i=1:3, j=1:3])

3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 2  4  6
 3  6  9

julia> display([i*j for i=1:3, j=1:3 i>=j])

6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 6
 9
```

not a surprise.  what i'd like is:
    3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
     1
     2  4
     3  6  9

i suppose a for loop is needed.  what i don't want is to generate the entire array and then filter out or replace the ones.

while the example is symmetric, it not really relevant to the q. any f(i,j) could be substituted for i*j.  (symmetric or not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you wanted to write `[i*j for i=1:3, j=1:3 if i>=j]`. The `if` condition will always make your result a vector.

What you can do to avoid generating an entire array is e.g.:

```
x = Matrix{Int}(3,3)
for i in 1:3, j in 1:i
    x[i,j] = i*j
end
y = LowerTriangular(x)
```